# URL rewriting : css, js, and images not loading

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I've following rule for `.htaccess`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]

RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1
```

It redirects `http://localhost/detail/123` URL to `http://localhost/detail.php?id=123`. The page redirects successfully, but the problem is `CSS, JS, and images` are not loading,

CSS, js files are located under `http://localhost/css/` and `http://localhost/js/`

One solution is to use **absolute path** (ex /CSS, or /js rather than just CSS/, /js but this does not seem a reliable solution since we've to change it on all files,

Any other solution based on `.htaccess` rules, which is independent of editing all PHP files and let us use "relative paths"?

Comment: you should use absolute path based on your system e.g. if you using linux it would be something like `/var/www/css/`

Comment: ¿Where exactly are your css and js directories?

Comment: they are at `http://localhost/css/style.css` and `http://localhost/js/js.js`

Comment: Also i have to make an empty directory, in this case "details" for the rewrite to work, is there a way around it?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Don't be lazy and change your relative URIs in your resources to root directory absolute pathing like `/css/style.css`. This is the best.

You can get clever and use regex and replace all the files you need which would be like a few one liners and you're done. How many places could there be to change? And you should be using a template.

This should work but I wouldn't go this way.

`RewriteRule ^detail/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]`

Comment: do you mean that i should use "Absolute Paths" in all my resources ? Rather than "Relatives"

Comment: @BhaveshGangani kind of yes, but **not** the kind with the protocol and domain `http://example.com/css/style.css`, but this type of root directory absolute pathing: `/css/style.css`

Comment: Would be great to have the comment clarification in the main body :)

Comment: Thanks @Joe - I've made the improvement.

Answer (score 24):

> one solution is that use absolute path (ex /css, or /js rather than just css/, /js but this is not looks a reliable solution since we've to change it on all files,

This is because your relative URIs have their base changed. Originally, the base is `/` when the page is `/detail.php?id=123`, and the browser properly fills in relative links with the `/` base. But when the browser goes to a page like `/detail/123` the base suddenly becomes `/detail/` and it tries to append that in front of all relative URLs and thus none of them load.

You can either make your links absolute, or change the URI base in the header of your pages (inbetween the `<head> </head>` tags):

```
<base href="/">
```

Comment: any other solution rather than editing the actual php, html files ( eg. `.htaccess` file rules)

Comment: Thanks Jon. Fastest and neatest solution.

Comment: This one helped me `<base href="/project/">` and I don't have to change the path for all my scripts or css files. Thank you Jon.

Answer (score 7):

I applied url rewriting to a project in core php. I faced the same problem. css, Js and images were not getting loaded. I used this and it worked for me. [Source](http://forum.kohanaframework.org/discussion/7500/best-way-to-modify-example-htaccess-to-allow-js-css-png-in-views/p1)

```
# Allow any files or directories that exist to be displayed directly
RewriteCond ${REQUEST_URI} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} \.(gif|jpe?g|png|js|css|swf|php|ico|txt|pdf|xml)$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Anthony's answer is perfectly valid, and he is actually trying to impart some good practices there.

However, since you do not seem content with that answer, here is a different solution. Just insert this line into your .htaccess before any Rewrite-Command:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/detail/((css|js)/.*)  /$1
```

It will redirect all the originally 404 requests for /details/css/style.css and /details/js/js.s to their actual location. Neither particluarly pretty nor elegant, but it simply works.

Answer (score 0):

this code perfectly work for me, add before redirect rule(RewriteRule ^detail/([0-9]+)/?$ detail.php?id=$1)

```
RewriteRule ^(.+)/(admin|css|fonts|ico|include|js|images)/(.*)$ $2/$3 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

**just exclude directory it will load automatically that's it**

```
RewriteRule ^(css|js|fonts|images|plugins)($|/) - [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

my issue resolved when i changed the style link from

```
 <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

into   `<link href="/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />`