# .htaccess rewrite css images and fonts not working

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, url-rewriting

am doing small script want .htaccess redirect php to html files friendly.

my script:

index page: `http://localhost/rko/index.php`

images in: `http://localhost/rko/images/`

css files: `http://localhost/rko/css/`

css fonts: `http://localhost/rko/css/`

js files : `http://localhost/rko/js/`

i want convert page variable (page) to be (page).html like:

`http://localhost/rko/index.php?page=index` to `http://localhost/rko/pages/index.html`

and convert `http://localhost/rko/products.php?name=$productname&id=$id` to:

```
http://localhost/rko/products/$id/$productname.html
```

i tried much to do that with code:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule pages/(.*)/\.html$  test.php?pages=$1
RewriteRule pages/(.*)\.html$  test.php?pages=$1

# Convert ?pages to pages.html
# eg. http://localhost/rko/products/id/5/
RewriteRule products/id/(.*)/ products.php?id=$1
RewriteRule products/id/(.*) products.php?id=$1
```

page vairbles (page) works:

```
http://localhost/rko/pages/index.html
```

but breaks (css, images, js, fonts)

i problem like mine in topic:

[URL rewriting : css, js, and images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883273/url-rewrite-css-js-images-not-showing)

code:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/(css|js|img)/(.*)?$ /$1/$2 [L,QSA,R=301]
```

but shows css path as (`http://localhost/css/`).. it removed script name (rko)

it should be (`http://localhost/rko/css/`)

if u pleased help me with this and also products page:

```
http://localhost/rko/products.php?name=$productname&id=$id
```

to

```
http://localhost/rko/products/$id/$productname.html
```

Comment: Perhaps you could find a friend with better English to help you improve this question? I'm afraid I can't make much sense of it.

Comment: Open Chrome dev tool or Firebug and see what 404 you're getting for css/js in `Net` tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you do not need to rewrite css images and fonts.
Just add in your html page header:

```
<base href="/">
```

or

```
<base href="http://localhost/">
```

Comment: i did both of them.. nothing happened sorry

Comment: You can use absolute path for css or image folder. (http://www....) because you rewrite your link, you change your "root", you have to indicate where is the new position. And all the links (in html) need to be relatives to <base or absolute.