# htaccess : Getting incorrect reference paths

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have following directory structure

```
server_root/Project1/(all_files_including_.htaccess)
```

I have written following rule

```
RewriteRule ^cost-calculator/([a-z]+)/$ cost-calculator.php?in=$1
```

for page

```
cost-calculator.php?in=seattle
```

Firstly, page doesn't work until I add `/` at the end of URL. Secondly, its not loading js,css files. The path being generated for these files are like `cost-calculator/seattle/js/jquery.min.js`. Why `cost-calculator/seattle` is prefixed for the `css/`, `js/` files?

What's wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883273/url-rewriting-css-js-and-images-not-loading

Answer (score 1):

For the first question : you have a trailing slash in your RewriteRule, it will only match if there *is* a trailing slash in your url. Try an interrogation mark to set the slash as optional : `([a-z]+)/?$`

For your second question : it seems like the page includes "js/jquery.min.js". This url is relative to the current page and the full path is resolved by the browser. When you are on "/cost-calculator/seattle/", the full path will be "/cost-calculator/seattle/js/jquery.min.js". The easiest fix is to give the full path for your css/js resources : `src="/full/path/to/js/jquery.min.js"`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Regarding first problem, to be generic, I applied this to my rule of removing extensions `RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/?$ $1.php [NC,L]` but here when I add `/` I still get 404 error

Comment: The slash needs to be excluded from the pattern, try `^([^\./]+)/?$`

Answer (score 1):

Always consider to use absolute path (`/the/file/path` or full address eg. `http://the/file/path`). Don't be lazy and change your relative URIs in your resources. This is the best.

Refer the answered questions here, [URL rewriting : css, js, and images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883273/url-rewriting-css-js-and-images-not-loading)