# Problems with CSS while using RewriteRule on .htaccess

Tags: html, css, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, localhost

I'm having some trouble while using RewriteRule on my local and remote servers.

Here's the situation I'm in right now:

```
localhost/puntvallesgit/index.php?seccion=nosaltres
```

this is the actual URL

I want it to be renamed to:

```
localhost/puntvallesgit/nosaltres
```

and

```
localhost/puntvallesgit/nosaltres/
```

Both urls work, meaning, it does not give me a 404 or something like that, but, with the second one (localhost/puntvallesgit/nosaltres/) there's no CSS nor JS loading correctly.

Looking the html code, I can see that while using the rule, the url path for JS and CSS gets changed to:

localhost/puntvallesgit/nosaltres/css/styles.css
yet the code itself has this:

```
<link href="./css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

I understand that sine I'm rewritting the url, to /nosaltres ... the html code adapts to that new folder structure, but that is not the expected behaviour.

Also, while using the url without the final slash (localhost/puntvallesgit/nosaltres) it works great (under localhost).

I could use absolute paths, yet, that is not the most ideal thing to do, since then paths would change from my localhost to my remote server

Here's the htaccess rewrite i'm using:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?seccion=$1 [NC]
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ index.php?seccion=$1 [NC]
</IfModule>
```

Some advice please?
Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [URL rewriting : css, js, and images not loading](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883273/url-rewriting-css-js-and-images-not-loading)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the base tag between the `<head> </head>` section of your site. Then your asset folders will read from the root.

```
<base href="/">
```

Also rewritecond only works for the first rewrite following it. You can condense your rule this way.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/?$ index.php?seccion=$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: sorry, I was testign stuff, and pressed enter here without knowing and this published.

It sends the paths to localhost/css/styles.css instead of /puntvallesgit.

If I put <base href="/puntvalles"> or <base href="/puntvallesgit/"> does not work properly either :S

Comment: So `puntvallestgit` is your root directory?

Comment: And what directory is your .htaccess located in?

Comment: puntvallesgit is my root on local, remote is listed under /pvbootstrap

htaccess is besides the index.php

Comment: It appears localhost is your root or setting the base to / wouldn't have made it localhost/css/style.css.  It you want it to be identical to remote server you should use the real document root and not a subfolder. Meaning `localhost/nosaltres`

Comment: /nosaltres is a section of the website, not the root folder.

Localhost should look like this
localhost/puntvallesgit/nosaltres (about us page) yet, new secction should be localhost/puntvallesgit/news

And that should be done via url params like index?section=news or ?section=about etc

Answer (score 0):

This is not `htaccess` related (although your rewrite rules are not optimal), but rather a problem in the way you load your stylesheet.

When browsing to `http://localhost/puntvallesgit/nosaltres/`, the browser will try to load your stylesheet from `./css/styles.css` which translates to `http://localhost/puntvallesgit/nosaltres/css/styles.css`, while your stylesheet is probably at `http://localhost/puntvallesgit/css/styles.css`.

You should use `/puntvallesgit/css/styles.css` as the source of your stylesheet instead.

Comment: Actually it is .htaccess related, because he added the non existent URI and doing a Rewrite. So the base now becomes /nosaltres which gets appended to relative URI. It's a pretty common issue with rewriterule making them into folders from query strings. Dun needs to either use absolute paths or base tag to his root.

Comment: This would still happen using better rewrite rules, so the problem is the source of the css file - not the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: That's right, you have to keep changing them. But you could avoid that by storing the web address (or at least the root folder) in a variable that changes when you're running the website on your local or remote server. For example by including a config file (`include_once('config.php');`) which has different variables on the different servers.

Comment: @redelschaap so, the remote server is a subdomain pointed to a subdirectoy (/pvbootstrap)

So, this solution messes with that too, since now things point to subdomain.domain/folderwichsubdomainpointsto/resturl

Comment: For browsers it doesn't matter whether your website is on a subdomain or not, as long as your paths are valid. If your remote website is at the root of a (sub)domain (`http://sub.domain.com/`), then your css/js paths start with `/` (e.g. `/css/style.css`. When your remote website is within a folder (`http://localhost/folder/` or `http://www.domain.com/folder/`), your css/js paths start with that folder: `/folder/css...`

Comment: my remote server has the website under pvbootstrap subfolder.
the subdomain points to that subfoler as root

That is the problem.
I can see it properly if I enter the full path (no subdomain, yes subfolder on url), yet, if I enter via the subdomain(pointed directly into subfolder) it won't work properly, that is why I was trying to aboid absolute paths.

Comment: What is the URL of your website?

Comment: You should remove the `pvbootstrap` folder from you css/js/images paths on the remote website, and include them on the localhost website. Screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/9719519/2015-06-01/pv.png

Comment: I just saw that your test website is also running on http://www.pieraedicions.com/pvbootstrap/ and that's working fine now. Most hostings point subdomains to folders within the root having them both accessible. Maybe it's an idea when you test it on that address? Once finished you just remove the folder from the css/js/images paths.

Comment: the problem with removing the /pvbootstrap/ from the code comes when I enter to the /nosaltres section, where it gets added to the paths wich puts me in the same spot I asked help with :S

Comment: Well both http://pieraedicions.com/pvbootstrap/ and http://pieraedicions.com/pvbootstrap/nosaltres work fine here...

Comment: yes, those do, but not under subdomain, and I'll have to test how does it do when moved to a root folder instead of a subfolder, but well, for now, I guess that will do, I'll test under full path url instead of the subdomain. Should be able to move it arround with just fixing the path sent by config.php, will see

Comment: Yes, when you're done and you move from `domain.com/folder/` to `domain.com`, just remove `pvbootstrap/` from the css/js/media paths and everything works fine.