# Rewrite rule .htaccess joomla 1.7

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

Hi I been trying to rewrite a particular url by modifying the .htaccess of joomla but so far i couldn't make it work.
Here it is the line:

```
RewriteRule ^/service http://www.example.com/tag1/service.php [NC,L]
```

I think is because the rest of the joomla htaccess directives are taking over and in that way i get the message 'Article not found'

Any idea on how can I use rewrite urls using joomla?

Comment: I found the problem why that rule wasn't working, so to start one has do delete the first / from service, so the rule goes RewriteRule ^/service http://www.example.com/tag1/service.php [NC,L]. And the second point one has to write the rules in the proper place, in the case of Joomla one has to look for the block ## Begin - Custom redirects
Now the problem I have is because they are all relative paths, when the rule is followed I don't see any image or anything... Any idea on how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: See the @Jon-lin 's answer on 
http://stackoverflow.com/a/12887204/3160747