# Path issue with rewrite rule in htaccess file

Tags: javascript, php, html, .htaccess

One of my WAMP project's directory structure is as follows:

```
localhost/mywebsite
-includes
-assets
-.htaccess
-header.php
-index.php
-news_list.php
```

In the homepage there are numerous hyperlinks like `<a href="news_list.php?catid=1">Politics</a>,<a href="news_list.php?catid=2">Sports</a>` etc.

When any of the said hyperlink is clicked then `'news_list.php'` would load with stories of appropriate category.Now the 'news_list.php' page generally loads
news stories inside  and at the bottom of that page is a `pager` like `<prev>1,2,3....10<next>`

In order to make the url's more user friendly, i am using some RewriteRule in a .htaccess file.Thus a link like

`localhost/mywebsite/news_list.php?catid=2` would look like `localhost/mywebsite/sports/2`.

My .htaccess file looks like:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^politics/([0-9]+)\/?$ news_list.php?catid=$1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^sports/([0-9]+)\/?$ news_list.php?catid=$1 [NC]
```

On the 'news_list.php', i'm facing **two** issues.First the 'news_list.php page' loads appropriate data from the database but, **no images are displayed neither
any css rules are applied to the page content**.Secondly, **the pager does not work.When i click on page-2,page-3.. etc.it tries to load contents of page-2 or page-3 etc, but it immediately redirects back to index.php**.

My pager code is as follows:

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <?php if(!empty($total_pages)):for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++):
      if($i == 1):?>
          <li class='active'  id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href='mcat_pagination.php?cid=<?php echo $catid;?>&page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
      <?php else:?>
          <li id="<?php echo $i;?>"><a href='mcat_pagination.php?cid=<?php echo $catid;?>&page=<?php echo $i;?>'><?php echo $i;?></a></li>
      <?php endif;?>
  <?php endfor;endif;?>
</ul>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var cat_id=<?php echo $catid;?>;
        $('.pagination').pagination({
            items: <?php echo $total_records;?>,
            itemsOnPage: <?php echo $limit;?>,
            cssStyle: 'light-theme',
            currentPage : 1,
            onPageClick : function(pageNumber) {
                jQuery("#target-content").html('loading...');
                jQuery("#target-content").load("mcat_pagination.php?cid=<?php echo $catid;?>&page=" + pageNumber);
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope that i have been able to describe my problem properly.Please help me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: The “no images, no CSS” problem is something many newbies face. Not going to vote to close as a duplicate (because your question contains a second problem as well), but this is something you should be able to figure out without further help, if you do some research. http://stackoverflow.com/q/12883273/1427878, https://www.google.com/search?q=rewrite+no+images+no+css

Comment: for your second problem, I think it's due to you are using urls in links (href to a) if you are using jquery load then don't use links with same href. instead you can use `javascript:void(0);`.