# CSS not loading after URL rewriting

Tags: php, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite URL from `example.com/test.php?id=hd3j3` to `example.com/id/hd3j3`.
The problem is rewriting occurs and I am taken to the page but the css and js of the page doesn't load. Where am I going wrong?

**.htaccess**

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id/([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: to find your answer hope this will help you
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883273/url-rewriting-css-js-and-images-not-loading">just click on this link</a>

Comment: to find your answer hope this will help you
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883273/url-rewriting-css-js-and-images-not-loading">just click on this link</a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite rule looks right for me.

Maybe your css gets loaded from a relative path and not absolute ?

`<link href="css/layout.css">`

The browser try to load from example.com/**id**/css/layout.css instead of example.com/css/layout.css

Comment: So what do you actually suggest?

Comment: `<link href="/css/layout.css">`

Comment: Ok, that seems to do the work. But isn't there any other way so that I dont require to change the file paths?

Comment: You add a <base href="http://example.com/"> in the <head> tag. So u dont need to change all file paths.

Comment: What about RewriteCond ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to clear the cache and retry ! This usually works.Or set the root path correctly.
If these won't work try this,
If you want to use image tag and show to correctly images, use 
" />

Comment: Nopes, Cache clear and retrying didn't work. Absolute paths needs to be set. But I need a better way using htaccess. Or else I will need to sit and change paths for many files.