# PHP .htaccess Redirection

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi I'm having a problem with my redirection rule. Currently i redirect all page to index.php and the routes will check the correct controller.

1. Everything works fine if the request is `localhost/project/home`
2. But if if change the request to `localhost/project/home/` all links are not working.

This is the folder architecture:

[image]

This what it looks like on `localhost/project/home`:

[image]

This is what it looks like on `localhost/project/home/`:

[image]

This is my `.htacess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.*+)$ index.php?path=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: This line: `localhost/project/home/` means: `localhost/project/home/index.php/`

Comment: How would i get it to redirect to root index.php ?@SalimIbrogimov

Comment: I think the problem is that you can't load `.css` and `.js` files, right?

Comment: Yes @SalimIbrogimov. I tried excluding it on .htaccess but its not working. Still new to .htaccess

Comment: please, check the `url` of `.css` and `.js` files!

Comment: its home/css/{file}.css

Comment: but the content is also the index.php

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883273/url-rewriting-css-js-and-images-not-loading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems your css files are not loading because it is not getting the correct path. Better if you can use baseUrl in your css links as follows.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://localhost/project/css/style.css">
```

Comment: Is there any solution that can use relative urls?

Comment: There can be some solutions for it.

But

It is better to build a function to get the baseUrl (http://localhost/project/) from your system and append the balance part ('css/style.css'). Thats the way, we use css, javascript links in most popular PHP frameworks such as Zend, Laravel and etc.