# hiding url using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I want to hide my url path using .htaccess my url looks like www.example.com/user/f1/f2/f3/  inside my f3 folder I have an index.php file and related css files with it.

now I put my .htaccess file inside user folder and it looks like

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ f1/f2/f3/index.php?username=$1 [L]
```

when I run www.example.com/folder/abcd  i just getting the index file only other css files are not working. what was the problem. any one please help

Comment: _“what was the problem”_ - the same as always – that some people apparently can get no grasp whatsoever, on how resolving of relative URLs works …

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewriting : css, js, and images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883273/url-rewriting-css-js-and-images-not-loading)