# About RewriteRule .httaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

well, i have a question, is there any possible chance to pass parameters from a tag and bring into?

i mean i have the a tag:
`<a href="CATEGORIES/$value">sent to $value categories</a>`

and in rewrite rule i don't know if i can send an random value

`RewriteRule ^CATEGORIES  index.php?page=categories [NC,L]`  
this is my actual CATEGORIES and i want to pass a value from a tag and to show like
`RewriteRule ^CATEGORIES  index.php?page=categories&anothervalue= [NC,L]`  
`localhost/CATEGORIES/$value`  not like  `localhost/CATEGORIE?var = $value` 
and $value to be anothervalue value

Without messing up all my styles!
I work in localhost!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewriting : css, js, and images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883273/url-rewriting-css-js-and-images-not-loading)

Answer (score 0):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1&value=$2 [NC,L]
```

Test :

URL : localhost/mycategory/test

index.php

```
echo $_GET["page"]
echo $_GET["value"]
```

Comment: the problem is i need with this format ```index.php?page=categories```and after that to come my desire value

Comment: Like this ? "localhost/mycategorytest/value1"
so
`RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)/([^\.]+)$ index.php?page=$1&value=$2 [NC,L]`
Test on your code : 
`echo $_GET["page"]`
`echo $_GET["value"]`

Comment: I have updated my initial post, copy paste should be work

Comment: technically this should work but it destroy my all styles