# Favicon is not showing when I put / at the end of URL in PHP website

Tags: .htaccess, url, favicon

I have a website made with PHP we have rewritten some URLs using htaccess to remove **.php** but now when I put **/** at the end of URL the favicon is not showing
**link without slash** https://www.seosolutions.at/webdesign-wien
link wish slash https://www.seosolutions.at/webdesign-wien/

here is my htaccess code

```
Options +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch 
RewriteEngine On
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^seosolutions\.at [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.seosolutions.at/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteRule ^app-entwicklung app-entwicklung.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^blog blog.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^impressum impressum.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^uber-uns uber-uns.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^kontakt kontakt.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^local-seo local-seo.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^logo-erstellung logo-erstellung.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^mobile-seo mobile-seo.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^offpage-seo offpage-seo.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^webdesign-wien webdesign-wien.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^onpage-seo onpage-seo.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^seo-agentur-wien seo-agentur-wien.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^social-media-management social-media-management.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^was-ist-javascript was-ist-javascript.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^was-ist-on-page-seo was-ist-on-page-seo.php  [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^was-ist-react was-ist-react.php  [L,NC]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [URL rewriting : css, js, and images not loading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12883273/url-rewriting-css-js-and-images-not-loading)

Answer (score 0):

**Without** the trailing `/`, the favicon is being fetched from:

```
https://www.seosolutions.at/assets/images/favicon.png
```

**With** the trailing `/`, the favicon is being fetched from:

```
https://www.seosolutions.at/webdesign-wien/assets/images/favicon.png
```

In your markup, the path to the favicon is :

```
./assets/images/favicon.png
```

The leading `./` here tells it to look relative to the current path.

Without the trailing `/`, your path `/webdesign-wien` points to a page **named** `webdesign-wien` in the path `/`. So the favicon is found relative to `/`.

When you add the trailing `/`, you are adding a new layer to the path. So your page looks for the image relative to this path. `/webdesign-wien/`.

Changing the path to your favicon to be absolute from the root directory will allow it to show up on every page.

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.png">
```