# htaccess redirect hiding the php extension or pass a parameter

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I'm using a main index.php file to handle the most of requests, so my basic .htacess looks like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441140/using-htaccess-rewrite-redirect-so-single-php-file-can-display-data-according-to):

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

But i've got some requests (like /signin or /signout) that needs to be handled directly from .php file with the same name (/signin.php and /signout.php).

So my .htaccess rules needs to be: "`if %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php` does not exists redirect to `/index.php?page=$1` else redirect to `%{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php`".

How can i do this?

Comment: By using a RewriteCond analog to the ones you already have in place to check whether or not an existing file is matched and a corresponding RewriteRule.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,QSA]
```

This will send everything to `/index.php` that is not a valid file or directory and doesn't have a matching `.php` existing in your filesystem.

Comment: It doesn't work. When i check an exsists file i got 404 not found error (/signin not redirect to signin.php).

Answer (score -1):

you could handle this in your index.php, just redirect every call on index.php. There you can readin all parameters given in URL.

```
$aParams = explode("/", $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
```

Now you can handle all parameters and redirect if you need to.

Comment: Yes, but is not what i've asked.